# Как в битриксе фильтровать товары с ТП по складам?

Tags: битрикс, фильтр

Как в битриксе фильтровать товары с торговыми предложениями по складам? Бесплатный модуль в маркетплейсе такие товары отсевает, региональность поступает так же. 
Используется готовое решение Аспро Next

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь свойства у ТП со складами, вешаешь обработчики на изменение количество товара по складам, и дальше умный фильтр сам подтянет свойства и будет фильтровать вот тут магазины это склады для примера https://www.kemp1.ru/catalog/avto_tovary/avto_aksessuary/avtokresla_detskie/bustera/filter/stockdom-from-1-to-5/stockyas-from-1-to-1/apply/

Comment: Если так делать то он выводит полностью товар со всеми ТП, то есть есть те которых нет на выбранном складе, а есть на другом, а этого нужно избежать